# Check which table each row is from

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I want to output data from multiple data, with different output for each table the item is from.

```
SELECT * 
FROM subscriptions, albums, videos, pictures 
WHERE subscriptions.site = '$user' 
AND (subscriptions.site = albums.site 
     OR subscriptions.site = videos.site 
     OR subscriptions.site = pictures.site)
```

This is how I think it should be output.

```
while($item = $resultA->fetch_assoc()) {

  if(album){
    echo 'album';
  } 
  if(videos){
    echo 'video';
  }     
  if(pictures){
    echo 'picture';
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need change your query a litle bit. Im assuming `video`, `album` and `picture` have same struct, other wise you need match the columns.

And check for column type in your php

```
SELECT *, 'album' as type
FROM subscriptions s 
LEFT JOIN albums a 
        on s.site = a.site
WHERE subscriptions.site = '$user' 

union 

SELECT *, 'videos' as type
FROM subscriptions s 
LEFT JOIN videos v 
        on s.site = v.site
WHERE subscriptions.site = '$user' 

union 

SELECT *, 'pictures' as type
FROM subscriptions s 
LEFT JOIN pictures p 
        on s.site = p.site 
WHERE subscriptions.site = '$user'
```

---

But if you struct are very different you can bring all columns. Or choose the one relevant to you.

```
SELECT s.*, p.*, v.*, a.*
FROM subscriptions s 
LEFT JOIN pictures p 
        on s.site = p.site 
LEFT JOIN videos v 
        on s.site = v.site
LEFT JOIN albums a 
        on s.site = a.site
WHERE subscriptions.site = '$user'
```

In this case you have to chain multiple check if `column is null` to detect which site type are you handling.

**This is my guess**

I would need to know your table schema to use right field members. You have to rename fields to be unique in the query.

in this case `a.site as "a.site"`

```
while($item = $resultA->fetch_assoc()) {
    if ($item."a.site" is not null) {
       echo 'album';
    }
    else if ($item."v.site" is not null) {
       echo 'video';      
    }
    else 
       echo 'picture';
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, could you please elaborate more on how I would detect which site type it is?

Comment: Depend, you need help with the sql or reading the php part? If is sql you like option 1 or option 2 better? And will be better if you provide some sample data and schema. Like [THIS](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/85c4e/6)

Comment: The sql works, but now I need help with the php part please.  And option 2 works well for me.

Comment: Í'm more a `C#` guy. I update my question on how should be. But syntaxis may be wrong. So if still give you problem you may create a new question on how process a sql in php or search in web. if the query help solve that part consider upvote and select this as the answer.